# Django Model: many-to-many or many-to-one?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm just learning django and following a tutorial. I have a Link and a Bookmark. Unlike the tutorial I'm following, I would like a link to be associated with only one Bookmark, but a Bookmark can have multiple links. Is this the way to setup the model?

```
class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    bookmark = models.ForeignKey(Bookmark)

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(maxlength=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    links = models.ManyToManyField(Link)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Remove `links` from the Bookmark model, and to access the Link objects for a specific Bookmark you will use `bookmark.link_set.all()` (where bookmark is a specific Bookmark object). Django populates the reverse relationship for you.

Or if you so choose, provide your own [related name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the `bookmark` ForeignKey, such as "links" if you do not like "link_set".

Answer (score 4):

It's enough to define the relationship in one of the models. Django will automatically create an attribute in the other model.

If you want a link to be associated with only one bookmark, define a foreign key in `Link` that refers back to a `Bookmark` object:

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    bookmark = models.ForeignKey(Bookmark)
```

To access the links of a bookmark, use `bookmark.link_set`. This attribute is automatically created by Django.

Answer (score 1):

No, remove the `links =` statement from `Bookmark` -- what's predefined for you in bookmark is a property `link_set` that's the query for the links whose bookmark is this one (you can rename that property, but there's really no need).

Answer (score 1):

if i change the code as this 
eg:
    class Bookmark(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

```
class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    bookmark = models.ForeignKey(Bookmark)
```

is right relationship for them,